# Why does dispatchTouchEvent avoids clicks on the screen?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I've made an *easter egg* on my application that needs a touch combination to work. It works fine, but I cannot do any other click on the screen.
My class extends `FragmentActivity`, so I can't use `onTouchEvent`.
If I remove the overridden method `dispatchTouchEvent`, I can click normally.

My code:

```
                public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Window.Callback {
                  private ImageView animEaster;
                  private AnimationDrawable animDrawable;

                  @Override
                  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   ....
                  }
    @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                if (!isAtivado) {
                    easter = "";
                    isAtivado = true;
                    System.out.println("Ativou");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                int count = event.getPointerCount();
                easter += count;
                if (count <= 2) {
                    if (isAtivado) {
                        System.out.println("Desativou");
                        isAtivado = false;
                        if (easter.equals("5435432")) {
                            animEaster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            lblProdDes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            lblProdDes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if (Servidor.servidor.equals("???????")) {
                                lblProdDes.setText("DESENVOLVIMENTO");
                            } else {
                                lblProdDes.setText("PRODUÇÃO");
                            }
                            animDrawable.start();
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    animEaster.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    animEaster.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    lblProdDes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    animDrawable.stop();
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
....
```

My *easter egg* works, but the clicks doesn't.

Comment: Call me crazy, but it doesn't look like you tell your code to do anything other than if it is an easter egg. What is supposed to happen if it is just a normal click?

Comment: Oh no, you're not crazy, this is just a piece of code. It has some buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you need to call super.dispatchTouchEvent(). If you don't, events will never get dispatched to other views. Looks like instead of "return true;" at the end this should be "return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);".